# Edit VBA to paste multiple sheets as values into new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

The code from [this forum](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/450640-visual-basic-applications-copy-active-worksheet-values-only.html) is what I used as a starting point. I am trying to modify it to copy multiple sheets and paste them all as values, instead of just one sheet.

I copied multiple sheets using `worksheets(array(1,2,3)).copy`. I think the problem is `With ActiveSheet.UsedRange` because it is only replacing the first sheet as values and leaving the remaining sheets as formulas.

What do I need to change so that all the sheets paste as values?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets(Array("Sheet 1","Sheet 2","Sheet 3").Copy
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
    wbNew.SaveAs "L:\Performance Data\UK Sales\Sales (Latest).xlsx"
    wbNew.Close True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the sheets:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.UsedRange.Value = ws.UsedRange.Value
Next ws
```

So, with your code, you could do it like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim wbOld As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet, delWS As Worksheet
Dim i       As Long, lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
Dim shts()  As Variant
Dim rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set wbOld = ActiveWorkbook

shts() = Array("Sheet 1", "Sheet 2", "Sheet 3")
Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
Set delWS = ActiveSheet
wbOld.Worksheets(Array("Sheet 1", "Sheet 2", "Sheet 3")).Copy wbNew.Worksheets(1)
delWS.Delete

For i = LBound(shts) To UBound(shts)
    With wbNew.Worksheets(shts(i))
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
        rng.Value = rng.Value
    End With
Next i

wbNew.SaveAs "L:\Performance Data\UK Sales\Sales (Latest).xlsx"
wbNew.Close True

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note: I am not sure which workbook you want to paste the values in. As it is above, it does this in the COPIED workbook, not original.

Comment: Thank you for your response!

I am trying to paste the values in the **copied** workbook, as you said. The original workbook should keep all formulas. 

However when I tried this code, it pasted the values in the original sheet and ran out of memory while looping. Is there a way to limit how many loops it does?

Comment: @tenvfa - See the updated code. Does that work? If it's running out of memory, you may want to check the size of `UsedRange`...how big do you expect it to be?

Comment: Your edit fixed the issue of copying values to the new workbook only, so thank you. 

It ran out of memory again and the debugger flagged 
`wbNew.Worksheets(shts(i)).UsedRange.Value = wbNew.Worksheets(shts(i)).UsedRange.Value` as the error. I am a total VBA beginner with no coding experience, so I'm not sure I understand your question about size.

The largest sheet contains cell values in 15 columns by 25,000 rows. The smallest sheet has 15 columns by 2,000 rows.

Comment: @tenvfa - Is all the data in a "block", i.e. do all columns have the same rows of data? If I wanted to get the last row with Data in it, is Column A safe to use on each sheet? If not, what column has the most data?

Comment: Yes, the data is in a block and Column A is safe to use. I don't know if it is relevant, but one sheet has 22 columns instead of 15.

Comment: @tenvfa - See my edit again. I whittled down the range to (I assume/hopefully) only use the used ranges. Also added `ScreenUpdating = False`

Comment: There is an issue where the first sheet of the new workbook is being deleted. I think it originates here: 

`Set delWS = ActiveSheet
wbOld.Worksheets(Array("Sheet 1", "Sheet 2", "Sheet 3")).Copy wbNew.Worksheets(1)
delWS.Delete`

The 3 copied sheets are pasting in front of the blank "Sheet 1" on the new workbook. If they were to paste after the blank sheet, I think that would fix the issue. I played with it for a few minutes but can't get them to move. 

**However**, the blank sheet doesn't interfere, so I just deleted all references to `delWS` and the file works! :)

Comment: @tenvfa - Ah, yeah I added that delete line just because I assumed you wouldn't need it. Otherwise, glad to hear it's working!